# What is the Delta V from the Moon to Earth Sun L1?

Tags: the-moon, trajectory, delta-v

There are various proposals to build infrastructure at Earth/Sun L1 point, such as discussed in this [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/63293/26356). From LEO the Delta V cost to L1 is about [3.5 kms](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/35627/26356) or about kg of propellant in LEO for every kg needed at L1, doubling needed payload to LEO on a project where final mass is already in millions of tonnes.

For this reason a number of proposals have presumed getting most of the structural mass from the moon.

The naive assumption using that answer and [charts used here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35495/26356)  would put the Delta V cost of Moon surface to L1 at around 3kms, similar to LEO. In theory it should be possibly to gravity assist from the Earth to lower that a bit, and also use a fixed launcher on the surface to reduce the needed fuel, but even combining those two there would need to be thrust to take station at L1.

Is it possible to determine a Delta V from Lunar surface to Earth Sun L1 assuming clever/slow trajectories, and how much of that could come from a fixed launch system vs later maneuvers?

Comment: related paper:  [Preliminary Trajectory Design for NASA's Solar Cruiser: A Technology Demonstration Mission](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343658233_Preliminary_Trajectory_Design_for_NASA%27s_Solar_Cruiser_A_Technology_Demonstration_Mission) found with "trajectory optimization to Sun Earth L1".  Probably coming at the question from the complicated side

Comment: @ErinAnne nice find on how you go about planning things like this, and gives some proper numbers for Earth C3 to reach L1 rather than the SE answer I used.